# Joomla\Filesystem\File or Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\File

Tags: namespace

The JED Checker recommends in Joomla 4 using

```
Joomla\Filesystem\File
```

isteand of

```
Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\File
```

because of the second one being deprecated in J5.

But when i use it things like this happen:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "exists" of class
> "Joomla\Filesystem\File".

So whats the deal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newer `Joomla\Filesystem\File` which is part of the Joomla Platform, there is no longer the method/function called `exists()`

The exists() method called in the Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\File can be replaced by the standard PHP `is_file()` function.

This is the exists() function in Joomla 3.

```
/**
 * Wrapper for the standard file_exists function
 *
 * @param   string  $file  File path
 *
 * @return  boolean  True if path is a file
 *
 * @since   1.7.0
 */
public static function exists($file)
{
    return is_file(Path::clean($file));
}
```

Comment: I see, and `getExt` is gone to.

Comment: Among others. There are 13 methods in the original CMS version and only 8 in the platform version.

Comment: I dont get it. In J5 there is still `Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\File` in `TemplateModel` e.g being used. Why does the JED Checker say it needs to be replaced in J5 and where is the "platform version" ?

Comment: The Framework file can be found in ..\libraries\vendor\joomla\filesystem\src\File.php

Comment: So what can be done with `getExt` ? Should i still use `Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\File` for that

Comment: I would suggest where the usage is within the context of the CMS, of which Templates are, then you would use the \Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\CMS while if the usage is not specific to the CMS then you would use the platform class in \Joomla\Filesystem\File. The original post shows no context around the message from JED so I can't be more specific as to the best choice for you.

Comment: OK, thanks 4321 :)

Comment: The \Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\File is depreciated from 4.4 and will be removed in 6.0 therefore it still exists in 5.x but is marked as depreciated.

Comment: So that means if its deprecated from 4.4 and will be removed in 6.0 the context answer no longer matters?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'context answer'.

Comment: It will be removed from 6.0. So `\Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\CMS` cannot be used anymore.